# Open angularjs popup using jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

How can open AngularJS popup using jQuery?

If this possible please help me.

How can call this function in jQuery?

```
onclick="angular.element('#task_info_modal').scope().show_task_info_modal_by_ele(this)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an AngularJS callback bound to an element, you can simply use the `click` function of jQuery : `$('#my_element').click();`

But remember that mixing AngularJS and jQuery is most of the time a bad smell.